# Getting the error while trying to run the code for selenium/selenide script to execute script on browserstack

Tags: selenium, appium, ios-ui-automation, browserstack

Error description -

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver of the given context doesn't implement io.appium.java_client.FindsByIosNSPredicate nor io.appium.java_client.FindsByFluentSelector. Sorry. It is impossible to find something

Please help me if someone have any idea about it.
will add more details, if someone wants.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the element locator strategy FindsByIosNSPredicate and FindsByFluentSelector is not being captured by the default appium version. Can you try explicitly mentioning the appium version capability and pass the same as passed while executing your tests locally on a real device. You may refer to this: https://www.browserstack.com/automate/capabilities or https://www.browserstack.com/app-automate/capabilities ( for App )